# Python: unexpected behavior with printing/writing escape characters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to read a file that may contain strings that include `\\`, `\n`, and `\t`, and I want to write those to another file as `\`, newline, and tab.  My attempt with `re.sub` doesn't seem to be working in my `.py` file, but it seems to be working in the interpreter.

Here's the function I wrote to try to achieve this:

```
def escape_parser(snippet):
    snippet = re.sub(r"\\", "\\", snippet)
    snippet = re.sub(r"\t", "\t", snippet)
    snippet = re.sub(r"\n", "\n", snippet)

    return snippet
```

which causes `sre_constants.error: bogus escape (end of line)` when the backslash replacement line is included, and doesn't appear to replace the literal string `\t` or `\n` with a tab or newline when I comment out the backslash line.

I played around in the interpreter to see if I could figure out a solution, but everything behaved as I'd (naively) expect.

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Mar 24 2014, 02:28:52) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> test = "for(int ${1:i}; $1 < ${2:STOP}; ++$1)\n{\n\t$0\n}"
>>> import re
>>> test = "for(int ${1:i}; $1 < ${2:STOP}; ++$1)\n{\n\t$0\n}"
>>> print(re.sub(r"\n", "\n", test))
for(int ${1:i}; $1 < ${2:STOP}; ++$1)
{
    $0
}
>>> print(test)
for(int ${1:i}; $1 < ${2:STOP}; ++$1)
{
    $0
}
>>> test
'for(int ${1:i}; $1 < ${2:STOP}; ++$1)\n{\n\t$0\n}'
>>> t2 = re.sub(r"\n", "foo", test)
>>> t2
'for(int ${1:i}; $1 < ${2:STOP}; ++$1)foo{foo\t$0foo}'
```

As for actually writing to the file, I have

with open(os.path.join(target_path, name), "w") as out:
        out.write(snippet)

Although I've tried using `print(snippet, end="", file=out)`, too.

Edit: I've looked at similar questions like [Python how to replace backslash with re.sub()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585349/python-how-to-replace-backslash-with-re-sub/10585406#10585406) and [How to write list of strings to file, adding newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429064/how-to-write-list-of-strings-to-file-adding-newlines), but those solutions don't quite work, and I'd really like to do this with a regex if possible because it seems like they're a more powerful tool than Python's standard string processing functions.

Edit2: Not sure if this helps, but I thought I'd try to print what's going on in the function:

```
def escape_parser(snippet):                                                                                                                                                                                       
    print(snippet)                                                                                                                                                                                                
    print("{!r}".format(snippet))                                                                                                                                                                                 

    # snippet = re.sub(r"\\", "\\", snippet)                                                                                                                                                                      
    snippet = re.sub(r"\t", "\t", snippet)                                                                                                                                                                        
    snippet = re.sub(r"\n", "\n", snippet)                                                                                                                                                                        

    print(snippet)                                                                                                                                                                                                
    print("{!r}".format(snippet))                                                                                                                                                                                 

    return snippet
```

yields

```
for(int ${1:i}; $1 < ${2:STOP}; ++$1)\n{\n\t$0\n}
'for(int ${1:i}; $1 < ${2:STOP}; ++$1)\\n{\\n\\t$0\\n}'
for(int ${1:i}; $1 < ${2:STOP}; ++$1)\n{\n\t$0\n}
'for(int ${1:i}; $1 < ${2:STOP}; ++$1)\\n{\\n\\t$0\\n}'
```

Edit3: Changing `snippet = re.sub(r"\\", "\\", snippet)` to `snippet = re.sub(r"\\", r"\\", snippet)` as per @BrenBarn's advice, and adding a test string in my source file yields

```
insert just one backslash: \\ (that's it)
"insert just one backslash: \\\\ (that's it)"
insert just one backslash: \\ (that's it)
"insert just one backslash: \\\\ (that's it)"
```

So I must have missed something obvious.  It's a good thing one doesn't need a license to program.

Edit4: As per [Process escape sequences in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python), I changed `escape_parser` to this:

```
def escape_parser(snippet):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    print("pre-escaping: '{}'".format(snippet))                                                                                                                                                                   

    # snippet = re.sub(r"\\", r"\\", snippet)                                                                                                                                                                     
    # snippet = re.sub(r"\t", "\t", snippet)                                                                                                                                                                      
    # snippet = re.sub(r"\n", "\n", snippet)                                                                                                                                                                      
    snippet = bytes(snippet, "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")                                                                                                                                                    

    print("post-escaping: '{}'".format(snippet))                                                                                                                                                                  

    return snippet
```

which works in a sense.  My original intention was to only replace `\\`, `\n`, and `\t`, but this goes further than that, which isn't exactly what I wanted.  Here's how things look after being run through the function (It appears `print` and `write` work the same for these. I may have been mistaken about `print` and `write` not matching up because it appears the editor I was using to inspect the output files wouldn't update if new changes were made.):

```
pre-escaping: 'for(int ${1:i}; $1 < ${2:STOP}; ++$1)\n{\n\t$0\n}'
post-escaping: 'for(int ${1:i}; $1 < ${2:STOP}; ++$1)
{
    $0
}'
pre-escaping: 'insert just one backslash: \\ (that's it)'
post-escaping: 'insert just one backslash: \ (that's it)'
pre-escaping: 'source has one backslash \ <- right there'
post-escaping: 'source has one backslash \ <- right there'
pre-escaping: 'what about a bell \a like that?'
post-escaping: 'what about a bell  like that?'
```

Comment: Your test string does not contain any backslashes and your replacement isn't doing anything, as you can see when you do `print(test)`.  By typing `\n` in the test string, you're including an actual newline in the string, not the string backslash-n.

Comment: It's the same as the line it's reading from the source file, so I thought that seemed like the best candidate to try and test in the interpreter, but you're right.

Comment: "… because they're a more powerful tool than Python's standard string processing functions…" is not a very good reason if you don't have any need for that power in your use case, and _especially_ if it's actively getting in the way.

Comment: Also, if you're just trying to process Python-style backslash escapes, why not just ask Python to backslash-unescape instead of doing it manually? (If you specifically want to _only_ unescape these three characters, or you're planning to build up to Perl or C backslash escapes instead of Python, etc., then ignore this comment.)

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell if this is your main problem without seeing some data, but one problem is that you need to change your first replace to:

```
snippet = re.sub(r"\\", r"\\", snippet)
```

The reason is that backslashes have meaning in the replacement pattern as well (for group backreferences), so a single backslash is not a valid replacement string.