# How to save data to a file on separate items instead of one long string?

Tags: python, file-io

I am having trouble simply saving items into a file for later reading. When I save the file, instead of listing the items as single items, it appends the data together as one long string. According to my Google searches, this should not be appending the items.

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
with open('Ped.dta','w+') as p:  
    p.write(str(recnum))  # Add record number to top of file  
        for x in range(recnum):    
            p.write(dte[x])        # Write date  
            p.write(str(stp[x]))   # Write Steps number
```

Comment: Why do you think this should not be appending the items? When you call `write` on a file, it just writes whatever string you pass it to the current write position in the file, which is exactly what you're seeing. If you want things separated in some way, you have to explicitly write some appropriate kind of separator.

Comment: Meanwhile, what are the types of those objects? Just writing `str(…)` for some arbitrary thing may not get you something that you can read back in any useful way. Sometimes this is fine (e.g., if the thing is an int, you can just do `int(line)` at read time), but if it's something more complicated, like a list of dicts or a numpy array or the like, you will probably want to pick a file format rather than just write stuff and hope you can figure out what to do with it later.

Comment: Python's `write` is too low-level; you want to write a CSV file.  Look into Python `csv` or [pandas.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write list of strings to file, adding newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429064/how-to-write-list-of-strings-to-file-adding-newlines)

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not show your data or your output I cannot be sure. But it seems you are trying to use the `write` method like the `print` function, but there are important differences.

Most important, `write` does not follow its written characters with any separator (like space by default for `print`) or end (like `\n` by default for `print`).
Therefore there is no space between your data and steps number or between the lines because you did not write them and Python did not add them.

So add those. Try the lines

```
p.write(dte[x]) # Write date
p.write(' ') # space separator
p.write(str(stp[x])) # Write Steps number
p.write('\n') # line terminator
```

Note that I do not know the format of your "date" that is written, so you may need to convert that to text before writing it.

---

Now that I have the time, I'll implement @abarnert's suggestion (in a comment) and show you how to get the advantages of the `print` function and still write to a file. Just use the `file=` parameter in Python 3, or in Python 2 after executing the statement

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Using `print` you can do my four lines above in one line, since `print` automatically adds the space separator and newline end:

```
print(dte[x], str(stp[x]), file=p)
```

This does assume that your date datum `dte[x]` is to be printed as text.

Comment: If you think the problem is that the OP expects write to work with `print`, why not show him how to just use `print` with `file=`?

Comment: @abarnert: I tried to show as little change as possible from the OP's original code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a newline (`'\n'`) character at the end of your lines as you see in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects). This should solve the problem of *'listing the items as single items'*, but the file you create may not be greatly structured nonetheless.

For further of your google searches you may want to check [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization), as well as `json` and `csv` formats, covered in python standard library.

You question would have befited if you gave very small example of `recnum` variable + original `f.close()` is not necessary as you have a `with` statement, see [here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file).